# How to unload a dll which gets loaded by System.load(path to dll)

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Is there any way to unload a DLL which gets loaded in the application using System.load() API call.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a separate [ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) to load the dll. The dll is only bound to the ClassLoader it was loaded with. When the ClassLoader isn't used anymore (means no references to the ClassLoader exist), the garbage collector will free your ClassLoader and unload your dll.

Comment: That's the easiest way. I've also used a stub library that performs the loading of the real one from within the JNI code, that way I controlled it's loading an unloading explicitly.

Comment: @Petesh 
Could you explain your approach a bit more. How exactly you handled unloading part?

Comment: @KamalJoshi You can see code examples here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140704120535/http://www.codethesis.com/blog/unload-java-jni-dll