# Call Native (DLL) code from Java using JNI keeps variables c++ initialized every new recall function

Tags: java, c++, swing

I'm using a call native code from a Java (vr1.7) application (as the code below), from a GUI with swing.

```
public class ImageProcessContainer {

    static {
        System.load("c:\\ImageProcDLL.dll");
    }

    native public int processImage(String filename, String args);

    public int execute(String filename, String args){

        return processImage(filename, args)

    }
}
```

When I call the first time, the code works perfectly. From the second call before the code runs but the C variables continue with data from the previous session!

Why does this happen?

The variables in C++ code are not static! Fragment code C++ below. The global variables are kept initialized.

For example: variables corner1 and corner2 (both globals) its some of continue initialized

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <time.h>
//Some others includes

#include "ImageProc.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat frameFeed;
Point corner1, corner2;
Rect box;

.
.
//some other globals


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL _processImage (JNIEnv * env, jclass, jstring filename, jstring buffer){
        return processVideo(NULL, NULL);
}

int processVideo(char * filename, char * buffer) {

    namedWindow("Video Process");

    //Initializing some local variables
    int inc                 = 0;
    ImageProc * imageproc = NULL;
    .
    .
    //some code here

    while(capture.read(frameFeed) && !terminateApp){
        if (startImageProc) {
            if (!imageproc) {
                int securityArea = 10;
                Point p1, p2;

                p1.x = corner1.x;
                p1.y = corner1.y;

                p2.x = corner2.x;
                p2.y = corner2.y;

                imageproc = new ImageProc(1, box, p1, p2);
        } 
        if (initParameters){
            //Some code Here
            initParameters = false;

        } else {
            imageproc->analiseMoment(frameFeed);
        }
    }
    .
    .
    //some code here
    return 1;
```

}

Comment: You need to show how the variables on C++ side are declared.

Comment: There are a million things that could go wrong on the C++ side, not just variables being declared `static`. Show us the code.

Comment: Wojtek Surowka and  Christian Hackl: tks! I add c++ fragment code

Comment: I don't mean to annoy you, but we still have not come significantly closer to the issue. Your global variables are potential bugs, but the problem can only be identified within `processVideo`. By the way, use forward slashes for `#include` lines, regardless of whether you are on Windows or not!

Comment: And of course, if that's your real code, are you sure `_processImage` should discard all arguments passed to it and call `processImage` with null pointers?

Comment: Christian Hackl: Tks for your coment. This is the real code. At this time I´m not using the arguments

Comment: When you say " From the second call before the code runs but the C variables continue with data from the previous session!" before *which* code runs? How do you see the variables? So, it loads the dll, then each time you call a function in the dll the global variables have the same value... it's not reloading the dll each time you call your function, right?

Comment: doctorlove: When I call native code in the second time, pressing a button on GUI again after the code return. In the first time, the application c++ draw a rectagle based in a mouse pointer clicked. In the second call, the application C++ start with the rectangle drawed like previus.

Comment: @rwvaldivia: But where are the declaration and definition of `processVideo`? It's probably somewhere in ImageProc.h. How are we to know what happens in that function? How are we to know it's not just `int processVideo { return 1; }`?

Comment: @Christian Hackl: I edit and include the code on processVideo function. The variables corner1 and corner2 are two who is continue initialized after de return. The two variable are globals!

Comment: So, you load the dll once, call the function which initialises the variables, then call it again and wonder why they have values? Delete the globals.

Comment: @doctorlove: I laughed with your ​​answer. You are right. Pretty simple. But I think, once I load dll and terminate the process (return value) this is not still in memory. I cannot load the dll and unload after the call? Sorry if the question sounds basic.

Comment: You could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491043/how-to-unload-a-dll-which-gets-loaded-by-system-loadpath-to-dll but that would be a bit crazy - get rid of the globals. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem just make the global variables into local variables. Pretty simple. The problem is that once the dll is loaded into memory all the global variables with the values ​​are populated with data from the last call. [sugested by @doctorlove in comments].